# How to create a dynamic src within a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

```html
      <%foreach (Art a in SearchedArt)%>
   <%{ %>
    <tr>
     <td><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" src=<%a.PicturePath %>/></td>
     <td><%= Global.Users.Find(m => m.UserID == a.UserID).Name %></td>
     <td>
      <ul>
       <%foreach (string tag in a.Tags) %>
       <%{ %>
        <li><%= tag %></li>
       <%} %>
      </ul>
     </td>
    </tr>
   <%} %>
```

So what I am trying to do is display a different image for each piece of art in a table. However, src=<%a.PicturePath%> doesn't seem to be doing the trick (I tried it with quotations and it didn't work either). How do I do this?

Comment: Aren't you missing an equal sign inside? src="<%= a.PicturePath %>"

Comment: Oh yeah my original had the "="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asp:Image` is a server-side tag - you need to set its `ImageUrl` property from code behind or use a  client-side `<img>` and set its `src` attribute:

```
<img src="<% =a.PicturePath %>" />
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly